# How to pass data via post request to a field whose schema is an array of objects in WordPress REST API

Tags: wordpress, postman, wordpress-rest-api

So just starting out with **WordPress REST API**

I am **creating my own REST API Controller** (Meaning having my own class extending **\WP_REST_Controller** class)

I am exposing API routes for a Custom Post Type

*The code is very long so I won't paste all code here, just the important ones*

So everything so far is ok, I am able to read data from the routes and create data through the routes

**One issue I have is I am having trouble trying to send data through POST request for fields whose schema is array of object**

So given this schema

```
    $schema = array(
        '$schema'    => 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
        'title'      => $this->post_type,
        'type'       => 'object',
        'properties' => array(
            'id'          => array(
                'description' => __( 'Unique identifier for the survey cpt object.', 'wp-plugin-boilerplate' ),
                'type'        => 'integer',
                'context'     => array( 'view', 'edit', 'embed' ),
                'readonly'    => true,
            ),
            'title'             => array(
                'description' => __( 'The title for the survey cpt object.', 'wp-plugin-boilerplate' ),
                'type'        => 'string',
                'context'     => array( 'view', 'edit', 'embed' ),
            ),
            'description' => array(
                'description' => __( 'The description for the survey cpt object', 'wp-plugin-boilerplate' ),
                'type'        => 'string',
                'context'     => array( 'view', 'edit', 'embed' )
            ),
            'status'      => array(
                'description' => __( 'A named status for the survey cpt object.', 'wp-plugin-boilerplate' ),
                'type'        => 'string',
                'enum'        => array_keys( get_post_stati( array( 'internal' => false ) ) ),
                'context'     => array( 'view', 'edit' ),
            ),
            'type'        => array(
                'description' => __( 'Type of Post for the survey cpt object.', 'wp-plugin-boilerplate' ),
                'type'        => 'string',
                'context'     => array( 'view', 'edit', 'embed' ),
                'readonly'    => true,
            ),
            'fields'      => array(
                'description' => __( 'Set of fields for the survey cpt object.', 'wp-plugin-boilerplate' ),
                'type'        => 'array',
                'context'     => array( 'view', 'edit', 'embed' ),
                'items'       => array(
                    'type'       => 'object',
                    'properties' => array(
                        'field_type'  => array( 'type' => 'string' ),
                        'description' => array( 'type' => 'string' ),
                        'order'       => array( 'type' => 'integer' )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

So the **fields** field is an **array of objects**,

Just ignore authentication to avoid further complicating things for the mean time, I just allowed public creation of cpt items via REST API atm.

When I send a **POST** request via **postman** like this

[image]

**Note:** The operation above is successful if I **remove/not pass the fields** field.

So is there something wrong to the way I define the schema? or something wrong on sending the data?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Also tried this

[image]

**Edit:**

Confirm this is an issue only for **PostMan**, sending **POST** request via **AXIOS** works ok

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the **form-data option**, Can you try with **raw option** with below code:

```
{
    "title": "Test Survey 5",
    "description": "lalala"
    "status": "publish",
    "fields": {
        "field_name1": "value1",
        "field_name2": "value2"     
    }
}
```

Use your original field_name and value for "field_name1" and "field_name2".

Let me know if any query.

Thanks

Jenil

Comment: Can you share what error are you getting? Also Have you passed the Authorization when using POST method?